# NEXTJS 404 in deployment to docker, but not in dev environment

Tags: docker, next.js

for some reasin, Im getting 404 on my route that is actually working on local.
this is my next config:

```
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
     output: 'standalone',

  }
}
```

package jsong:     `"next": "13.1.1",`
When the app loads, I get this error:

```
Invalid next.config.js options detected: 
  - The value at .experimental has an unexpected property, output
```

What can I do? im using appDir, yet again, its working on local.

this is my docker image `FROM node:16-alpine`

Thanks

Comment: Same problem, do you have any new information?

Comment: @Artegon -  Sorry but no.... I moved back to react... I dont think its ready yet, too many experimental features...

Comment: I just found a solution, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place `output` not in `experimental`, but in first level of `module.exports`.

```
module.exports = {
  output: 'standalone',
  experimental: {
    appDir: true
  },
}
```